# Android Is there FourSquare Map Library

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, foursquare

I've seen some Android App using FourSquare Map Library. (Such As Instagram, Path, Kakao Place, etc...)

FourSquare Map is much sensible in gesture~ So I like to use FourSquare Map instead of Google Map.

Is there any foursquare map library?

They have different current position marker.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, there's no "Foursquare Map". According to [this Foursquare blogpost](http://blog.foursquare.com/2012/02/29/foursquare-is-joining-the-openstreetmap-movement-say-hi-to-pretty-new-maps/), they rely on the [OpenStreetMap project](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).

Apparently the developer documentation of OpenStreetMap is located on [this site](http://switch2osm.org/).

Hope this helps!

EDIT: an Android library for OpenStreetMap seems to exist, available [here](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/).

Comment: I show the OSM. This was for the Web~
I wanted to know which map "FourSquare", "Path", "InstaGram" uses for their Android App

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!!

The slow map gesture was because it was drawing markers from apis.

There is no foursquare map library

and Foursquare Kakao Place, Instagram just uses Google Map API 1!!!

I couldn't be able to test Map API 1 cause is has been blocked by google!!